# Как реализовать взаимодействие Python с Telegram Desktop

Tags: python, telegram

На самом деле у меня вопрос в том с помощью каких библиотек и как это вообще можно реализовать. Задача стоит в том что бы запустить Клиент Телеграма, получить там сообщение, изменить некоторые настройки аккаунта и закрыть.

Подскажите куда копать хотя бы, а куда не копать)) за ранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/) как вариант. Так же, посмотреть возможности разных библиотек, например [Telethone](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/index.html).

Comment: Спасибо, но это не много не то.. Нужно именно получить доступ к декстопной версии телеграма.. пока реализовал это с помощью pyautogui, но не нравится это решение.. )